# com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthException: Error getting access token for service account: Stream is closed. while uploading image to cloud storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I already use google cloud storage for couple of months, and this issue suddenly come up in 30 January 2023 and I don't know why.

I had setup credentials using key .json from IAM google cloud platform service account, and everything work fine in my local environment. But when application going to production in GKE I got the error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: Stream is closed, iss: refund@pg-user.iam.gserviceaccount.com
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:605) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$1.call(OAuth2Credentials.java:257) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$1.call(OAuth2Credentials.java:254) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31) ~[guava-31.0.1-jre.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$AsyncRefreshResult.executeIfNew(OAuth2Credentials.java:580) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.asyncFetch(OAuth2Credentials.java:220) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:170) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:1018) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:96) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions$1.initialize(HttpTransportOptions.java:159) ~[google-cloud-core-http-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
    at com.google.cloud.http.CensusHttpModule$CensusHttpRequestInitializer.initialize(CensusHttpModule.java:109) ~[google-cloud-core-http-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:91) ~[google-http-client-1.41.2.jar!/:1.41.2]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:521) ~[google-api-client-1.33.1.jar!/:1.33.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455) ~[google-api-client-1.33.1.jar!/:1.33.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565) ~[google-api-client-1.33.1.jar!/:1.33.1]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:311) ~[google-cloud-storage-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.lambda$internalCreate$2(StorageImpl.java:198) ~[google-cloud-storage-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
```

while uploading an image to google cloud storage

I have no idea why and how to solve this problem, I've tried so many different ways, like change service account key json, try to change cluster and other way. but still can't solve this proble

```
 Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Credentials)))
                .createScoped(Collections.singletonList(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL));

        return StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials)
                .setTransportOptions(HttpTransportOptions.newBuilder().
                        setConnectTimeout(300000)
                        .build())
                .setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
```

and here is the code for uploading to google cloud storage

```
 storage.create(BlobInfo
                .newBuilder(cloudStorageProperties.getBucketName(), filename)
                .setAcl(listAcl)
                .setContentType(FileUtils.getMimeType(extension))
                .build(), content);
```

and here is google library that I used id my gradle

```
 implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:24.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage'
```

I try to solve upload image problem to Google Cloud Storage with google client library, so I hope my application can work as usual, can uploading an image to google cloud storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several retries, finally I can solve this problem with using jetty instead of netty